# How does gnuplot understand command line arguments from stdin?

Tags: gnuplot

I generated a graph using `gnuplot` with following command:

```
echo 'plot [0:14][0:1000] "source_data_file" with steps title "example graph"; pause 15' | gnuplot
```

I would like to change the name of the X- and Y-axes with `xlabel` and `ylabel` arguments, but if I execute:

```
echo 'plot [0:14][0:1000] "source_data_file" with steps title "example graph" xlabel 'X-axe label' ylabel 'Y-axe label'; pause 15' | gnuplot
```

..I receive an error message pointing to `xlabel`. I have tried to separate arguments with semicolons, but this had no affect. In addition, I would like to change the format of the Y-axe from exponent(for example 1.8232e+06) to integers(for example 1823200), but I don't know how to pass the `format y`/`format x` argument to gnuplot.

How does gnuplot understand command line arguments if those are passed to gnuplot from stdin?

Comment: You have a problem with quotes. Depending on your shell, the way to solve this may vary. Precisely, you use single quotes for labels, but they are supposed to be in a single quoted string...

Comment: @arbautjc Could you explain this a little more. What do you mean by "they are supposed to be in a single quoted string"? IMHO they are already in the single-quoted strings. Or did you mean that "they are supposed to be in a double-quoted string"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@arbautjc is correct--you have a problem with using single quotes for the x and y axis labels.  Also, those need to be specified before the `plot` command is run.  So, a better way would be

```
echo 'set xlabel "X-axe label"; set ylabel "Y-axe label"; plot [0:14][0:1000] "source_data_file" with steps title "example graph"' | gnuplot -p
```

Also, is the `pause` command necessary?  (It may have some reason to be there, but I cannot see it from your example.)

Comment: I used `pause 15` to keep the generated graph open for 15 seconds. Otherwise the graph window will close immediately. However, the command you provided did not work with my gnuplot 4.4(patchlevel 3). I receive the "line 0: invalid command" error message..

Comment: I changed `echo 'xlabel "X-axe label"; ylabel "Y-axe label"; plot [0:14][0:1000] "source_data_file" with steps title "example graph" ; pause 15' | gnuplot` to `echo 'set xlabel "X-axe label"; set ylabel "Y-axe label"; plot [0:14][0:1000] "source_data_file" with steps title "example graph" ; pause 15' | gnuplot` and now it works as I needed. Thanks!